# How to fix CopyFile() error 5 - access denied error

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, copy

I am trying to write a copy file function that can be used on both Linux and Windows. It works on Linux, but on Windows, I get error code 5 when trying to use the WinApi function CopyFile().

**In header File.h**

This is the custom defined function in the File namespace that I should be able to use on both Linux and windows.

```
class File
{
public:
    static bool copyFile(std::string source, std::string destination);
private:
}
```

**In File.cpp**

For Linux it is simple:

```
#ifdef __unix__
  #include "File.h"
  bool File::copyFile(std::string source, std::string destination)
  {
      std::string arg = source + " " + destination;
      return launchProcess("cp", arg);
  }
#endif
```

In the Windows specific block of code, I use the WinAPI (#include < windows.h >) function CopyFile(). This accepts LPCWSTR data types instead of strings. To overcome this I have created a function that converts strings to LPCWSTR types.

```
#ifdef _WIN32    
  #include "File.h"
  #include <Windows.h>
  std::wstring strtowstr(const std::string &str)
  {
      // Convert an ASCII string to a Unicode String
      std::wstring wstrTo;
      wchar_t *wszTo = new wchar_t[str.length() + 1];
      wszTo[str.size()] = L'\0';
      MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), -1, wszTo,(int)str.length());
      wstrTo = wszTo;
      delete[] wszTo;
      return wstrTo;
  }


  bool File::copyFile(std::string source, std::string destination)
  {
      std::wstring wsource = strtowstr(source);
      std::wstring wdestination = strtowstr(destination);

      int result = CopyFileW(wsource.c_str(), wdestination.c_str(), TRUE);

          //for debugging...
          std::wcout << "The error is " << GetLastError() <<std::endl;
          std::wcout  << wsource.c_str() << std::endl;
          std::wcout << wdestination.c_str() << std::endl;              

      if (result == 0)
      {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
#endif
```

**In my Test Programme**

```
TEST(all,main_copy_file)
{
    std::cout << "Testing copyFile() function..." << std::endl;

    std::string srcDir = File::currentWorkingDirectory() + "srcDir";
    File::makeDirectory(srcDir);

    std::string destDir = File::currentWorkingDirectory() + "destDir/";
    File::makeDirectory(destDir);

    File::makeFile(srcDir, "testFile", ".txt");

    ASSERT_TRUE(File::fileExists(srcDir + "/testFile.txt")) << "Error: Test file has not been generated" << std::endl;
    ASSERT_TRUE(File::directoryExists(destDir)) << "Error: Destination directory does not exist" <<std::endl;

    ASSERT_TRUE(File::copyFile(srcDir + "/testFile.txt", destDir)) << "Error: Coppy unsucsessfull" << std::endl;
    ASSERT_TRUE(File::fileExists(destDir + "/testFile.txt")) << "Error: CoppyFile() flagged as sucsessfull but file does not exist" << std::endl;

}
```

**In the application Output (on Windows)**

```
/*
Testing copyFile() function...
The error is 5    
C:\GIT\CorteX\Externals\OSAL\build\Debug/srcDir/testFile.txt
C:\GIT\CorteX\Externals\OSAL\build\Debug/destDir/

error: Value of: File::copyFile(srcDir + "/testFile.txt", destDir)
Actual: false
Expected: true
Error: Coppy unsucsessfull
*/
```

Error code 5 is an access denied error. I think it gives this error when either the directory does not exist, the directory is open somewhere else, or I do not have permissions.

Since I have tested that the directory does exist, I think it must be one of the latter two. I might only have restricted Admin rights (I don't know), but I can paste into the "destDir" without admin permission. So maybe it thinks the directory is open? Is there a command that exists to make sure the directory is closed?

The test is successful when running on Linux.

Comment: note that C++ already offers functions to copy files.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of one/some of these functions?

Comment: you have no permissions. if somebody else open folder with exclusive access - will be another error - `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, if file/folder not exist - again will be another error. also this error in case file already exist and readonly

Comment: @Blue7 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy

Comment: @RbMm Do you have any guesses on why I do not have permissions? I am only trying to copy a file from one directory to another. Both of the files are in directories that are inside the current working directory, so I shouldn't have a problem, should I?

Comment: @Blue7 - hard to say. however this is usual situation for restricted account. need look for security descriptor (dacl,label of directory at begin). explorer use `IFileOperation` for copy. it can be autoelevated if running from exe from trusted location

Comment: @The Techel I tried using the function you provided, but when trying to include the header <filesystem>, I get the error: filesystem: no such file or directory.

Comment: either try <experimental/filesystem> or get a more recent compiler/toolchain.

Comment: `C:\GIT\CorteX\Externals\OSAL\build\Debug/destDir` ... The default permissions on the system partition (usually `C:`) are such that a standard user has only read access. These permissions are inherited by sub folders and files. It should work if you launch your program with elevated rights (right-click on the .exe file, "launch as administrator"). Alternatively use a destination directory where a standard user has write access, for instance the [temp directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: IIRC, the destination string is supposed to include the file name.  I suspect you're getting "access denied" because Windows thinks you want to replace the existing directory `destDir` with a file, and that's not considered a legal operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) API expects file names for both source and destination files. Your code passes a directory name for the destination. This causes the API to fail. You need to append the file name for the destination as well.

Besides that, there are several other issues with your code:

- The path separator on Windows is a backslash (`\`). Your are mixing forward slashes (`/`) and backslashes. Depending on the arguments passed, the system won't translate forward slashes to backslashes, before passing them on to lower-level file I/O API's.
- You are calling `GetLastError` too late. You need to call it **immediately**, whenever it is documented to return a meaningful value. Do not intersperse it with **any** other code, however trivial it may appear to you. That code can modify and invalidate the calling thread's last error code.
- Your code assumes ASCII-encoded strings. This will stop working, when dealing with files containing non-ASCII characters. This is quite common.
- `new wchar_t[...]` buys you nothing over `std::vector<wchar_t>`, except the possibility to introduce bugs.
- Your [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx)-based string conversion implementation makes (undue) assumptions about the code unit requirements of different character encodings. Those assumptions may not be true. Have the API calculate and tell you the destination buffer size, by passing `0` for *cchWideChar*.
- Your string conversion routine ignores all return values, making bugs ever so likely, and unnecessarily hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone who stumbles here needing more help:

CopyFile has the following constraints which if not met can give access denied error:

1. Insufficient permissions for the current user
2. File is in use
3. Filepath is a directory and not a file
4. File is read-only

In my case all the above were met, still I kept getting the same error. What helped me was a simple 
`SetFileAttributes(filePath,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)`

[Retrieving and Changing File Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/retrieving-and-changing-file-attributes)

[SetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesa)